# Codeigniter 4 - controllers won't work unless I add them directly to Routes.php

Tags: codeigniter, routes, controller, codeigniter-4

Can anyone tell me:
Do I have to declare all of my controllers in Routes.php in Codeigniter 4?

I can't seem to get a controller to work unless I add it directly to the "Routes.php"

I have created my controllers properly and the Home controller is working after install and setup.

If I add the controller My_page.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class My_page extends BaseController{

    public function index(){

        echo "Controller 'My_page' -> function index() ";


    }

}
?>
```

I get a
: "404 - File Not Found
Sorry! Cannot seem to find the page you were looking for."

If I now add the controller to the rout - i.e.:

```
$routes->post('my_page', 'My_page::index');
```

Then my controller works properly and I get the "Controller 'My_page' -> function index() " when I visit [www.mydomain.com/my_page](http://www.mydomain.com/my_page)

I have also tested:
[www.mydomain.com/index.php/my_page](http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/my_page)
and this makes no difference.

I am using the .htaccess that comes with the download. I have updated the base URL to [www.mydomain.com/](http://www.mydomain.com/)

The documentation is confusing to me - https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#setting-routing-rules ;

it sounds like they are saying have to declare all classes with routes?

**Why are my controllers not working without declaring them specifically in Routes.php?**

And am I misunderstanding '`setAutoRoute(true)`' it also does not seem to work - I expect that I can turn this on and simply create my controllers pretty much like in CI3?

Comment: see https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html#auto-routing-improved

Comment: Thanks - but I still don;t get it - are we supposed to add routes for every controller if auto-routing is not enabled? And I think it is not enabled by default? What I seem to be misunderstanding is - do we have to add those routes or not. All the demos I see of people setting up codeigniter - no-one mentions having to turn on out-routing nor adding routes.

Comment: @ChiKitomi yes. Beginning with version 4.2.0, AutoRouting is disabled by default. You will need to manually enable it inside your `Routes.php` file. This is a recent change, and while you have just recently started your project it's likely that these 3rd-party tutorials are not as recent. If it is enabled and still not working, you are likely doing something incorrectly. Look at the link above.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't enable auto-routing you most certainly need to add all routes which you are allowing, anything else will fail with error 404. As @parttimeturtle mentioned - autoroute it is disabled by default since 4.2.

So in short - **Yes, you need to add all controllers, their functions and the appropriate http methods**. (That includes CLI routes as well)

You can use $route->add(), which will allow all http methods, it's however more secure to explicitly set them with their methods.